# Chat welcome message missing the "Okay, I'll keep it in mind" button, hence can't be dismissed

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, design

This is what I see when entering the [Chemistry chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table):

> [image: Chat welcome message]

How can I dismiss the chat welcome message? It overlays the most important part of the chat – the last messages. There should be a way to dismiss this message. And it should be easy to discover.

Comment: See that slightly lighter white area?... Hover over it. That's the close button. Also, if you will tell the CMs which room you're in, they will be able to fix the CSS. This has happened in a couple of spaces... [here's](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/new-chat-welcome-message-ok-button-is-invisible) our question on the M&TV Meta.

Comment: I cannot not see the color difference on my monitor unless I change the settings.

Comment: That's fine... it's still a bug. If you look at the example I added to my comment, you can see how it's *supposed* to look. I'm guessing that you're in the Chemistry room?

Comment: @Catija if IͶΔ is there then yes, that's most likely Chemistry room. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard He goes in the ELL rooms, too... But, yes, that's how I guessed... plus the OP's logo. And it's confirmed. [Here](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/new-chat-welcome-message-ok-button-is-invisible) is the comment.

Comment: Yes, reproduced with Chrome latest version. @mhchem what browser you have?

Comment: Chrome on Win, Firefox on Linux. Looks the same in both.

Comment: Created http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/chat-welcome-message-missing-the-okay-ill-keep-it-in-mind-button-hence-can

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround until this is fixed, you can just put the following in your browser's Console:

```javascript
$(".dismiss-input-hint").click();
```

(enter press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to activate it)

This will have same effect as clicking the button you can't see, and the message won't appear again.

Comment: I learnt that I shouldn't run random code from random people off the internet ;P

Comment: @Uni so unlearn this! :D

Comment: If you were joking, lol. If you weren't, the $ is for jQuery, the .dismiss-imput-hint is the button, and .click clicks it. Nothing untrustworthy here!

Comment: @OldBunny2800 guess you are referring to Unikitty's comment? In such case, you should use `@` like I did here to notify, otherwise chances for the user to see your comment by chance are very low.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot. @UnikittyBlendsPeople, sorry about the wrong comment!

Answer (score 4):

As I answered to your post on [chemistry meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/chat-welcome-message-missing-the-okay-ill-keep-it-in-mind-button-hence-can), there were some styles that were incorrectly applied to the button on the chemistry chat styles, which I have now fixed.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I can now chat without having to answer how to get rid of that pop-up. :P